# infinite loops of for loop in python can be done?

Tags: python, c, loops, for-loop, infinite

how many times we can execute the print statement?

```
for i in range (1,6,-1):
   print(done)
```

The answer is none.
But in C language if we write this code it runs in infinite mode. Why?

```
int i;
for (i=5; i<=10; i--)
 {
     printf("what happens");
 }
```

I tried in python, it didnt even run but in C it ran infinite times, why?

Comment: In Python, the range `(1,6,-1)` is empty.  C doesn't have ranges.  In C, a `for` loop has three independent parts:  The initialization, the test, and the increment.  They aren't the same.

Comment: Because those two pieces of code are not functionally equivalent. `for` loops in C have the same keyword, `for`, but are not required to work at all like ones in Python. They both have completely separate and distinct definitions which you can look up.

Comment: Also, the correct C version of this loop is `for (i=1; i > 6; i--)`  This will behave the same as the Python loop, i.e. it will iterate zero times.

Comment: Your code C has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to [signed integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). This means that anything can happen, including your loop running forever or your loop terminating immediately.

Comment: I consider "Why do these vaguely similar looking codes in two different languages behave differently?" not a reproducable problem.

Comment: The C code will eventually stop, after it has hit the smallest (negative) number int can store, then it overflows (underflows?) and becomes very large positive, and the loop exits.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fundamental difference between *Python* and *C* *for* loops:

- *Python*: loop is performed on the elements of a (finite) sequence and continues as long there are elements left in it ([[Python.Docs]: Compound statements - The for statement](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement))
- *C*: loop continues as long a condition is met ([[CPPReference]: for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for)). To replicate the sequence iteration behavior, some languages have ***foreach***

As already suggested:

1. The *C* example in your snippet is not infinite, but relies on wrap around math (when an integral type bound is exceeded), and (for most implementations) will execute ***2<sup>32</sup> - 5*** times.
   If you want a truly infinite loop in *C*, use: **`for (;;)`**
2. You could use a ***while*** loop instead

Due to the nature of *Python*'s *for* loop, your desired behavior can't be replicated *OOTB*. But there are tricks (converting a *while* into a *for*).
And this can be done via [[Python.Docs]: itertools.cycle(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

> ```py
> >>> import itertools as its
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> it = its.cycle([None])  # Infinite iterable
> >>>
> >>> next(it)
> >>> next(it)
> >>> next(it)
> >>> next(it)
> >>>
> >>> for _ in it:
> ...     if input("Press 'n' to exit: ").lower() == "n":
> ...         break
> ...
> Press 'n' to exit: y
> Press 'n' to exit: 
> Press 'n' to exit: A
> Press 'n' to exit: Y
> Press 'n' to exit: t
> Press 'n' to exit: 1.618
> Press 'n' to exit: sdf54
> Press 'n' to exit: n
> >>>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent expression for the second code snippet in Python would be

```
i = 5

while i <= 10:
   print('what happens')
   i -= 1
```

Since `i` decreases by one every cycle and never goes above 10, the loop never exits.

Comment: And since Python has unbounded integer precision, it won't have the underflow problem that the C version has. It won't stop until `i` consumes all of memory.

Answer (score -2):

```
x = [1] 
for i in x:
    #your_works 
    x+=[1]
```